# Weird Tmux issue

Tags: terminal, tmux, iterm2

When attempting to split Tmux windows by using commands, I get the opposite effect of what one should expect:

The command

```
tmux split-window -v
```

Produces a **horizontal** split, while the command

```
tmux split-window -h
```

Produces a **vertical** split.

When attempting to split via the default keybinds it works as intended,

```
C-b %      # Produces a vertical split
# or 
C-b "      # Produces a horizontal split
```

It feels ridiculous to waste time on this, but something is borked, somewhere, somehow.  Can post tmux.conf if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default binding of Prefix+`%` (“vertical split” as you describe it) *is* `split-window -h` (see the output of `list-keys`).

It sounds like you may be thinking only of the orientation of the new pane divider. It may help if you instead consider “horizontal” and “vertical” as describing which dimension of the pane is being divided up to form the new pane.

`split-window -h` splits the *horizontal* space of a pane.

```
                                <#####|#####> horizontal space

+-----------+                   +-----+-----+
|           |                   |     |     |
|           |     Prefix %      |     |     |
|           |                   |     |     |
|           |  split-window -h  |     |     |
|           |                   |     |     |
+-----------+                   +-----+-----+
```

`split-window` (without `-h`) and `split-window -v` split the *vertical* space of a pane.

```
+-----------+                   +-----------+  ^  vertical space
|           |                   |           |  #
|           |     Prefix "      |           |  #
|           |                   +-----------+  -
|           |  split-window -v  |           |  #
|           |                   |           |  #
+-----------+                   +-----------+  v
```

The dividers necessarily end up with the opposite orientation.

Comment: Oh boy, why would they do that? Goes against the logical naming conventions of most Tiling WM's and Vim. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: It was probably done that way because it matches the *Emacs* convention.